# Using a timer in Go to trigger condition?

Tags: go, timer

I am trying to use a timer inside one of my functions so that I can create a delay on shooting projectiles on a game I am making. I have used Swift and the code would be something like this:

```
if someBool == false {
//call this function
func .....
someBool == true

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.02, repeats: false, block: { timer in
                self.someBool== false
            })
}
```

I am wondering if there is a very simple implementation to accomplish this, I am not overly concerned about performance as this is not a production project. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. In order to ask a question here you need to do some research on your own, then make an attempt at solving the problem. Once you've done that and you still can't get it to work you can come back here and show your code and ask for help. Have a look at the [help] section for more information on the site guidelines and how/what you can ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `time.After` (https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) in a goroutine:

```
func  myFunc() {
  ...
  if condition {
    go func() {
        <-time.After(interval)
       // Do things
    }()  
  }
...
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for, goroutines scare me a bit but that is very manageable and easier for me to understand when I see it implemented in the way I am trying to use it.